# What is the package name for JVM?

Tags: apt-cache

If I want to know if skype is installed, I would type this:

```
viggy@ubuntu:~$ apt-cache policy skype
skype:i386:
  Installed: 4.0.0.8-1
  Candidate: 4.0.0.8-1
  Version table:
 *** 4.0.0.8-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Or if Eclipse is installed:

```
viggy@ubuntu:~$ apt-cache policy eclipse
eclipse:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.7.2-1
  Version table:
     3.7.2-1 0
```

But let's say I want to know if the Java Virtual Machine is installed. How would I know what to pass to `apt-cache policy`? For example, you might not know what to pass to `apt-cache policy` for some programs:

```
viggy@ubuntu:~$ apt-cache policy java
N: Unable to locate package java
viggy@ubuntu:~$ apt-cache policy JVM
N: Unable to locate package JVM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for a program title using the following command:

```bash
apt-cache search TitleYouWant
```

This will search for any package that has the word in it.
Update the apt-get list of packages first using:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed **openjdk** then use

```
apt-cache policy openjdk*
```

In case of **sun-java** use

```
apt-cache policy sun-java*
```

This will show the version of java installed in your machine

Hope this helps